# Console animations

Tags: c#

I just want to know how to create simple animations like blinking, moving stuffs on C# console applications. Is there any special method for this?

Comment: +1 Loved this question, IMMD =)

Comment: For an example in practice, you can look at the [Kurukuru code](https://github.com/mayuki/Kurukuru/blob/f85a723923099ff273a7ed76fff08f05b456ffb0/Kurukuru/Spinner.cs#L79-L91); it's a plugin that generates a "spinner" in terminal (and uses the APIs suggested in the answers).

Comment: have a look at this https://gist.github.com/jplebre/fc2979cf2d1f23f93c89

Answer (score 71):

Traditional Console Spinner:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConsoleSpiner spin = new ConsoleSpiner();
        Console.Write("Working....");
        while (true) 
        {
            spin.Turn();
        }
    }

public class ConsoleSpiner
{
    int counter;
    public ConsoleSpiner()
    {
        counter = 0;
    }
    public void Turn()
    {
        counter++;        
        switch (counter % 4)
        {
            case 0: Console.Write("/"); break;
            case 1: Console.Write("-"); break;
            case 2: Console.Write("\\"); break;
            case 3: Console.Write("|"); break;
        }
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft - 1, Console.CursorTop);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 32):

Here is my spinner.  The purpose of it is to have a program do some work while the spinner displays to the user that something is actually happening:

```
  public class Spinner : IDisposable
  {
     private const string Sequence = @"/-\|";
     private int counter = 0;
     private readonly int left;
     private readonly int top;
     private readonly int delay;
     private bool active;
     private readonly Thread thread;

     public Spinner(int left, int top, int delay = 100)
     {
        this.left = left;
        this.top = top;
        this.delay = delay;
        thread = new Thread(Spin);
     }

     public void Start()
     {
        active = true;
        if (!thread.IsAlive)
           thread.Start();
     }

     public void Stop()
     {
        active = false;
        Draw(' ');
     }

     private void Spin()
     {
        while (active)
        {
           Turn();
           Thread.Sleep(delay);
        }
     }

     private void Draw(char c)
     {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(left, top);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.Write(c);
     }

     private void Turn()
     {
        Draw(Sequence[++counter % Sequence.Length]);
     }

     public void Dispose()
     {
        Stop();
     }
  }
```

And you use the class like this:

```
     using (var spinner = new Spinner(10, 10))
     {
         spinner.Start();

         // Do your work here instead of sleeping...
         Thread.Sleep(10000);
     }
```

Comment: Awesome example, exactly what I wanted: While I'm doing an intensive task I want some progressive

Comment: Please take a look at my anwser, I took your code and modified it a bit.

Comment: @ThisGuy: You provided the best example, really easy to understand and includes how it should be used in a multi-thread application, which is the key to a spinner. Thanks.

Comment: It seems your spinner class sometimes throws exception when I run the program from the console. It sounds like that it is related to the console window buffer size. Once I close and restart the console, problem goes away: `Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The value must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the console's buffer size in that dimension.
Parameter name: top
Actual value was 758.
   at System.Console.SetCursorPosition(Int32 left, Int32 top)
   at SecondaryReportCard.Spinner.Draw(String c)` 
https://i.ibb.co/W5W7P1F/dump1.png

Comment: I want to add (because I can't edit it any more), once I clear the console using `cls`, the problem goes away.

Comment: @Stack0verflow the exception is that the cursor position is invalid.  Maybe the cursor position the class is initialized with is wrong, or maybe you are writing to the console causing it to scroll?

Comment: @ThisGuy, yes, I've figured out. Each console window has a buffersize limit. I called your Spinner constructor as `new Spinner(0, Console.CursorTop + 1, 500);`, so the spinning characters are always drawn one line below the current CursorTop value. But when the buffer size is full, this throws the exception I got. I've fixed it by adding a few lines to the buffer whenever Console.CursorTop + 1 == Console.BufferHeight evaluates to true. Thanks @ThisGuy.

Comment: @Stack0verflow can you share your code, I've got the same issue happening and the only difference I can see with the sample is I comment out `this.left` and `this.top` in the constructor `public Spinner(ConsoleColor backgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black, int delay = 100)` (slightly modified). As you mentioned it only happens for me when the buffer is filled otherwise it works flawlessly.

Comment: @Lankymart you might try checking that the console position is within the window in the Draw method.  Also, I should be getting the current position, setting my draw position, then restoring the current position.  In this way, you can write to the console while spinning.

Comment: Thanks a lot. works great. I did change it a little so it would move the cursor to the next line after a console.write but it worked great without that change. thanks again.

Answer (score 10):

Great work with the ConsoleSpinner and the sequence implementation. Thanks for the code. I thought about sharing my customized approach.

```cs
    public class ConsoleSpinner
    {
        static string[,] sequence = null;

        public int Delay { get; set; } = 200;

        int totalSequences = 0;
        int counter;

        public ConsoleSpinner()
        {
            counter = 0;
            sequence = new string[,] {
                { "/", "-", "\\", "|" },
                { ".", "o", "0", "o" },
                { "+", "x","+","x" },
                { "V", "<", "^", ">" },
                { ".   ", "..  ", "... ", "...." },
                { "=>   ", "==>  ", "===> ", "====>" },
               // ADD YOUR OWN CREATIVE SEQUENCE HERE IF YOU LIKE
            };

            totalSequences = sequence.GetLength(0);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sequenceCode"> 0 | 1 | 2 |3 | 4 | 5 </param>
        public void Turn(string displayMsg = "", int sequenceCode = 0)
        {
            counter++;
            
            Thread.Sleep(Delay);

            sequenceCode = sequenceCode > totalSequences - 1 ? 0 : sequenceCode;

            int counterValue = counter % 4;

            string fullMessage = displayMsg + sequence[sequenceCode, counterValue];
            int msglength = fullMessage.Length;

            Console.Write(fullMessage);

            Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft - msglength, Console.CursorTop);
        }
    }
```

**Implementation:**

```cs
    ConsoleSpinner spinner = new ConsoleSpinner();
    spinner.Delay = 300;
    while (true)
    {
        spinner.Turn(displayMsg: "Working ",sequenceCode:5);
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there are [quite a few methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console_members.aspx) for this.

In particular, you may want to look at the following Console methods:

1. [SetCursorPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition.aspx) (you can move the cursor around, and overwrite elements)
2. [MoveBufferArea](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.movebufferarea.aspx) (copy/paste over the top of regions)
3. [ForegroundColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.foregroundcolor.aspx) and [BackgroundColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.backgroundcolor.aspx) (change coloring)

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to use `Console.ForegroundColor`, `Console.BackgroundColor` and `Console.SetCursorPosition(int, int)`

**EDIT**: For inspiration, [Let's Dance](http://franticflame.deviantart.com/art/Let-s-Dance-27458636)

Comment: I would love to see the Lets Dance animation's frames as text, so we can implement such an animation as a Console Spinner.

Answer (score 6):

Just saw this and a few other threads about it and love this kind of stuff!  I took Tuukka's nice piece of code and improved it a bit so the class can easily be set to just about any spin sequence.  I'll probably add some accessors and an overloaded constructor to polish it off and put it in the ol' toolbox.  Fun stuff!

```
class ConsoleSpinner
{
    int counter;
    string[] sequence;

    public ConsoleSpinner()
    {
        counter = 0;
        sequence = new string[] { "/", "-", "\\", "|" };
        sequence = new string[] { ".", "o", "0", "o"};
        sequence = new string[] { "+", "x" };
        sequence = new string[] { "V", "<", "^", ">" };
        sequence = new string[] { ".   ", "..  ", "... ", "...." };
    }

    public void Turn()
    {
        counter++;

        if (counter >= sequence.Length)
            counter = 0;

        Console.Write(sequence[counter]);
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft - sequence[counter].Length, Console.CursorTop);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I took the anwser from @ThisGuy and modified it a bit, but I noticed, that sometimes the row is not cleared as it should.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1");
        var tddf = XConsole.BusyIndicator("test 0 trtg fdfdfvdgd 4343", () =>
        {
            return "";
        });
        Console.WriteLine("2");
        var tdd = XConsole.BusyIndicator("test 0 trtg fdfdfvdgd", () =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1);
            return "";
        });
        Console.WriteLine("3");
        var t = XConsole.BusyIndicator("test 1 trtg vdgd", () =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            return "";
        });
        Console.WriteLine("4");
        var xt = XConsole.BusyIndicator("test 2", () =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            return "";
        });
        var xtx = XConsole.BusyIndicator("test 2 csds fsd fdsf ds s", () =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            return "";
        });

        Console.WriteLine("5");
        Thread.Sleep(4000);
    }
```

Spinner class:

```
    public class Spinner : IDisposable
    {
        private const string Sequence1 = @"/-\|";
        private const string Sequence3 = @".o0o";
        private const string Sequence2 = @"<^>v";
        private const string Sequence4 = @"#■.";
        private const string Sequence5 = @"▄▀";
        private const string Sequence = @"└┘┐┌";
        private string BusyMessage = "";
        private int counter = 0;
        private readonly int delay;
        private bool active;
        private readonly Thread thread;

        public Spinner(int delay = 200)
        {
            this.delay = delay;
            thread = new Thread(Spin);
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            active = true;
            Console.CursorVisible = false;
            if (!thread.IsAlive)
            {
                thread.Start();
            }
        }

        public void Start(string busyMessage)
        {
            BusyMessage = busyMessage;
            Start();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {          
            active = false;
            Console.CursorVisible = true;
            ClearCurrentConsoleLine();
            BusyMessage = "";
        }

private static void ClearCurrentConsoleLine()
{
    int currentLineCursor = Console.CursorTop;
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
    Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, currentLineCursor);
}

        private void Spin()
        {
            while (active)
            {
                Turn();
                Thread.Sleep(delay);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Draws the busy indicator
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="c">if empty char, then clear screen</param>
    private void Draw(char c)
    {
        int left = Console.CursorLeft;
        int top = Console.CursorTop;

        Console.Write('[');
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.Write(c);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
        Console.Write(']');
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(BusyMessage))
        {
            Console.Write(" " + BusyMessage);
        }

        //reset cursor position
        Console.SetCursorPosition(left, top);
    }

        private void Turn()
        {
            Draw(Sequence[++counter % Sequence.Length]);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Stop();
        }
    }
```

My console class:

```
public static class XConsole {
    public static T BusyIndicator<T>(Func<T> action)
    {
        T result;

        using (var spinner = new Spinner())
        {
            spinner.Start();

            result = action();

            spinner.Stop();
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static T BusyIndicator<T>(string content, Func<T> action)
    {
        T result;

        using (var spinner = new Spinner())
        {
            spinner.Start(content);

            result = action();

            spinner.Stop();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Why do I see this result sometimes?

```
1
2
3   st 0 trtg fdfdfvdgd    ]
4
[└] test 2 csds fsd fdsf ds s
```

Looks like the Dispose didn't trigger? Or a new `Task` alredy started?

It should look like this:

```
1
2
3
4
[└] test 2 csds fsd fdsf ds s
```

UPDATE:

I added `ClearCurrentConsoleLine();` and changed the `Draw` method, this fixed the issue.

Comment: The first two sleeps are less than the initial delay to draw (200 ms).  That is why the 3rd line is the first to display the message.  Your sleeps are happening in the callback, so they are all being kicked off in parallel.  You are printing the status at the current Console Position which changes during execution.  Hardcode left=0 and top=5 and you will see the output you desire.  With said, I don't quite understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Reading files from network share. With this the user will see that something is happening. It's reading a large amount of file and that takes a while with network share. The `Thread.Sleep` here simulates that.

Comment: Why do you have 5 spinners instead of single one since you are processing the file sequentially anyway?  If you meant for the them to be happening in parallel, you aren't doing this right.  All the spinners create their own thread, but the action() execution is happening on the main thread.

Comment: I fixed it. I added ClearCurrentConsoleLine();

Answer (score 1):

i'm not TOO sure i know exactly what you're on about. but i'll give it a shot.
I think the biggest and best way to cause the "blinking" affect (or what i think the blinking affect is) is to use a carriage return.
The best way to explain it to you is to show you the Foo Bar experiment.
start a new project, and in your Main function, try this.

```
Console.WriteLine("Foo/nBar");
```

The output will look like this

```
Foo
Bar
```

But if you use a carriage return.

```
Console.WriteLine("Foo/rBar");
```

The output will look like this

```
Bar
```

The reason is that Foo is written, then the carriage return takes you BACK to the start of the line, then Bar is written. All you ever see is Bar.
This can be helpful for "Moving" things on one line, instead of rewriting the same things again on multiple lines.
A way to do progression would be to use Console.Write();
Try this.

```
Console.Write("Loading");
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.Write(".");
}
```

The output should be

```
Loading
```

Followed by a Fullstop every second for 10 seconds.

If you combine the Carriage return with the Console.Write(); function you can write multiple things on a single line, clear the line and write something else, or indeed, the same thing just moved slightly. (This would of course need more than i have shown you, like recording where the "object" you are controlling is situated. If you would like a short example i would be happy to do one, just comment and ask me for it :)

Edit:
I noticed people mentioning colour, which i forgot. If you were doing animation i guess colour would be a must.
ForegroundColor and BackgroundColor are where it's at.
note that ForegroundColor will apply to the next characters written to the console, it will not completely recolour the Console.
/Edit

I hope this helps,

Skintkingle ;)

Comment: This does not, unfortunately, work for most cases.  You can't go UP a line with \r, so you're very limited without using Console.SetCursorPosition

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd chime in with my version of the previously listed code. Here it is:

```cs
class ConsoleSpinner
{
    bool increment = true,
         loop = false;
    int counter = 0;
    int delay;
    string[] sequence;

    public ConsoleSpinner(string sSequence = "dots", int iDelay = 100, bool bLoop = false)
    {
        delay = iDelay;
        if (sSequence == "dots")
        {
            sequence = new string[] { ".   ", "..  ", "... ", "...." };
            loop = true;
        }
        else if (sSequence == "slashes")
            sequence = new string[] { "/", "-", "\\", "|" };
        else if (sSequence == "circles")
            sequence = new string[] { ".", "o", "0", "o" };
        else if (sSequence == "crosses")
            sequence = new string[] { "+", "x" };
        else if (sSequence == "arrows")
            sequence = new string[] { "V", "<", "^", ">" };
    }

    public void Turn()
    {
        if (loop)
        {
            if (counter >= sequence.Length - 1)
                increment = false;
            if (counter <= 0)
                increment = true;

            if (increment)
                counter++;
            else if (!increment)
                counter--;
        }
        else
        {
            counter++;

            if (counter >= sequence.Length)
                counter = 0;
        }

        Console.Write(sequence[counter]);
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft - sequence[counter].Length, Console.CursorTop);

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
    }
}
```

Adds delay (unfortunately through `Thread.Sleep()` but, hey), the ability to loop the animation forwards and backwards (starts to reverse when it hits the end), and general improvements overall. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

This would be my prefered method:

```
public sealed class Spinner
{
    private static Lazy<Spinner> lazy =
        new Lazy<Spinner>(()=> new Spinner());

    public static void Reset()
    {
        lazy = new Lazy<Spinner>(()=> new Spinner());
    }

    public static Spinner Instance { get { return lazy.Value; }}

    private readonly int _consoleX;
    private readonly int _consoleY;
    private readonly char[] _frames = { '|', '/', '-', '\\' };
    private int _current;

    private Spinner()
    {
        _current = 0;
        _consoleX = Console.CursorLeft;
        _consoleY = Console.CursorTop;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        Console.Write(_frames[_current]);
        Console.SetCursorPosition(_consoleX, _consoleY);

        if (++_current >= _frames.Length)
            _current = 0;
    }
}
```

Call `Spinner.Instance.Update()` to start the spinner at the current position of the console. Any consecutive call will render the next frame at the same position.

Call `Spinner.Reset()` if you want to write more text and then add a new spinner at a new location.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way i solved it, sure it could/can be shorter but, Im just not that smart yet :-)

```
void cc() { Console.Clear(); }
void cr() { Console.ReadKey(); }

byte Sleeptimer = 90;
void sleepy() { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Sleeptimer); }




string[] Loading = { @"-- ", @"\  ", @"|  ", @"/  ", "Loading", " complete!" };

for (byte i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
{
    cc();
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
    Console.WriteLine(Loading[0] + Loading[4]);
    sleepy();
    cc();

    Console.WriteLine(Loading[1] + Loading[4]);
    sleepy();
    cc();

    Console.WriteLine(Loading[2] + Loading[4]);
    sleepy();
    cc();

    Console.WriteLine(Loading[3] + Loading[4]);
    sleepy();
    cc();

    if (i == 15) {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine(Loading[4] + Loading[5]);

        cc();
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
        Next();
    }
}
/*
    Now i feel even more noob while reading your code.
    I'm a newbie in programing.

    Guess this way would work if i just incfement the index of each Loading down below right?
    Learned too much today, forgot how this exactly works, to increment or to change the index i'd lile to acces

    Console.WriteLine(Loading[2] + Loading[4]);
    sleepy();
    cc();

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

This is animation with `cancellationToken`

````
        private static void ClearCurrentConsoleLine()
        {
            int currentLineCursor = Console.CursorTop;
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
            Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, currentLineCursor);
        }

        public static async Task Start(CancellationToken ct)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Console.WriteLine();
                string text = "Executing";
                for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
                {
                    if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
                        ClearCurrentConsoleLine();
                        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
                    ClearCurrentConsoleLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(text);
                    if (i == 3)
                    {
                        text = "Executing";
                        i = 0;
                    }

                    text += ".";
                }
            });
        }```
````